# Shader - Performance and functions

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, hlsl

I am creating vertex and fragment shaders and I would like to know if using functions inside my shader, for better readability, could have an impact on performance and optimisation.

Comment: they get inlined anyway

Comment: Should I understand that this is no impact on performance ?

Comment: Inlining means that function call is replaced by function body, so no impact.

Comment: There's a caveat though, there's no overhead if the arguments are declared `inout`, but if they are declared `in` (default), then a copy of the data needs to be made in order to prevent any changes in your function from propagating outside the function. But generally that's not an issue.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Will it always make a copy or could that also be optimised out if the complier determines no writes are being made to the `in` argument?

Comment: @LionelGuimaraes: Like I said, most of the time it's not an issue. You are absolutely right, it's only if you modify the value of one of the arguments the function is passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When considering the job of a compiler to optimize code, shaders provide some of the most ideal circumstances. They don't link to other files or libraries, the data-in/data-out is strictly defined and the language itself is limited. This allows your graphics drivers to very aggressively optimize your shader code.

Functions written in a shader will be compiled as though they were [inline](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson13.html). So you don't have to worry about those either. It's definitely worth your time to keep the code readable and user friendly. The compiler will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you, but I must say that there is a possibility to include files.

Comment: @MaT The compiler still sees the entire "program" and can optimize without having to consider calling conventions, etc. because there's just one compilation unit.